# Pass data in UIPageViewController between different swipe views

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on a project with 3 views that are accessed by swiping.

The following code implements the PageViewController I am using to handle the swiping motion:

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    lazy var orderedViewControllers : [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.newVC(viewController : "ClimaVC"),
            self.newVC(viewController : "WeatherVC"),
            self.newVC(viewController : "ClosetVC")]
    }()

    var myViewControllers = [UIViewController]()

    var currentIndex : Int = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.dataSource = self

        setViewControllers([orderedViewControllers[1]],
                           direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.delegate = self
    }


    func newVC(viewController : String) -> UIViewController {

        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1;

        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            // return orderedViewControllers.last
            //Return nil to avoid swiping forever.
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        currentIndex = previousIndex

        return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1;

        guard orderedViewControllers.count != nextIndex else {
            //return orderedViewControllers.first
            //Return nil to avoid swiping forever.
            return nil
        }

        guard orderedViewControllers.count > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
    }
}
```

The main View Controller is *WeatherVC*. In this view, time data is retrieved and stored in an integer variable named **timeOfDay**.

Depending on the value of **timeOfDay**, the background displayed will differ. While I was able to use this variable in *WeatherVC*, I need to pass this variable **timeOfDay** to the two other view controllers *ClimaVC* and *ClosetVC*.

I tried setting up a delegate protocol but failed, explored using the different functions provided by UIPageViewControllerDelegate and it did not get me anywhere.

I would really appreciate some help on this,

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not complicated, just assign the values at the pageviewcontroller datasources.

```
        import UIKit

                    class ClimaViewController: UIViewController{
            var timeOfDayClima: Int = 0

            override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewDidAppear(animated)
                print (timeOfDayClima)
            }
        }

        class WeatherViewController: UIViewController{
            var timeOfDayClima: Int = 0


            override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewDidAppear(animated)
               timeOfDayClima +=  1
            }
        }

        class ClosetViewController: UIViewController{
            var timeOfDayClima: Int = 0

            override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewDidAppear(animated)
                print (timeOfDayClima)
            }
        }
        class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

            lazy var orderedViewControllers : [UIViewController] = {
                return [self.newVC(viewController : "ClimaVC"),
                        self.newVC(viewController : "WeatherVC"),
                        self.newVC(viewController : "ClosetVC")]
            }()

            var myViewControllers = [UIViewController]()

            var currentIndex : Int = 0


            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

                self.dataSource = self

                setViewControllers([orderedViewControllers[1]],
                                   direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

                self.delegate = self


            }


            func newVC(viewController : String) -> UIViewController {

                return UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController)


            }

            func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

                //Guard = some kind of if statement.
                guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
                    return nil
                }



                let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1;



                guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
                    // return orderedViewControllers.last
                    //Return nil to avoid swiping forever.
                    return nil
                }

                guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
                    return nil
                }

                currentIndex = previousIndex


                if(currentIndex == 0) {
                    (orderedViewControllers.first as! ClimaViewController).timeOfDayClima = (orderedViewControllers[1] as! WeatherViewController).timeOfDayClima
                }

                return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]

            }

            func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

                //Guard = some kind of if statement.
                guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController)
                    else {
                        return nil
                }

                let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1;

                guard orderedViewControllers.count != nextIndex else {
                    //return orderedViewControllers.first
                    //Return nil to avoid swiping forever.
                    return nil
                }

                guard orderedViewControllers.count > nextIndex else {
                    return nil
                }

                currentIndex = nextIndex
                if(currentIndex == orderedViewControllers.count - 1) {
                    (orderedViewControllers.last as! ClosetViewController).timeOfDayClima = (orderedViewControllers[1] as! WeatherViewController).timeOfDayClima
                }


                if(nextIndex == 0) {
                    let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ClimaVC") as! ClimaViewController
                    secondVC.timeOfDayClima = 1
                }

                return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]

            }

            override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
                super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
                // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
            }


        }
```

Comment: There's some progress. ClimaVC receives the data but ClosetVC doesn't! I tested the values received and the console returns: CLIMA TIME OF DAY = 1
CLOSET TIME OF DAY = 0.

Comment: How come? The index of weather is 1 and closet is 2 while clima is 0

Comment: Just went over the code once again & I was missing the `currentIndex = nextIndex;`. Thank you very much for this solution, it worked perfectly fine & I hope that I'll be able to use the same method to pass the rest of my data!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try explaining what has failed in setting up your delegate protocol as well because it seems like it is likely the solution you are looking for. I'm writing a protocol here for reference but you have to change it according to your needs.

```
protocol WeatherVCDelegate {
    func changedTime(timeOfDay: Int)
}
```

Here comes the tricky part. When you declare a delegate in WeatherVC, you need to use the delegate to call the function to relay the timeOfDay to other weatherVC. How this works is that anything that conforms to the delegate protocol will be triggered to use the function.

```
class WeatherVC {
    weak var delegate: WeatherVCDelegate?

func functionName() {
    delegate?.changedTime(timeOfDay: value)
}
```

Now, when you initialize weatherVC in your PageViewController, you need PageViewController to conform to weatherVC delegate.

```
In PageViewController...
weatherVC.delegate = self
extension PageViewController: WeatherVCDelegate {
     ...
}
```

Here is more read up about delegates if my answer is not clear enough
https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the delegate part. So far, E.Coms' solution worked. However, I am going to need to pass data between my VC's again & I expect your post to be helpful!